# How to pass localstorage variable to different angularjs project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new to angularjs. I want to pass localstorage variable from one angularjs project to another angularjs project. Both projects are on same server.
I am passing localstorage variable from http://site1.in/ as,

```
window.localStorage.setItem('is_provider', 1);
```

and I want to use this localstorage variable to http://site2.in/.

I don't know how to get this variable in site2.
Please help.

Comment: You should atleast comment or vote up to  the answers to your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to pass data from one domain to another. You can use cross domain local storage to send data. I have used this and it's very simple. Refer to the site https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage

Answer (score 1):

You **can't**, `localStorage` is per domain specific.

Answer (score 0):

**Local Storage Privacy**

Website A and Website B would have their own local storage. Usually you would have to store certain information in a server database and sync it to the local storage.

I would use the local storage as a cache to get data once and update it at a certain interval depending on when I would want to invalidate the cache. For instance, you could sync with the server when the user A would log out and user B would want to login.

Have a look at the Privacy section in the HTML5 spec for Web Storage.

More information information and resources here: HTML5 Rocks.

**Testing**

I would suggest the use of a local server setup such as Linux/Mac/Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP stack (LAMP/MAMP/WAMP) to test on localhost (127.0.0.1).

Most browsers will limit you to 5 MB per domain for every window and tab because of the HTML5 spec recommendation.

I haven't tried this, but you could perhaps have a look at changing the port number of the localhost in Apache's httpd.conf (to do so, find Listen and change the port associated to it) and see if this will do the trick. Basically, you run each test under a different port number to have the whole storage limit for each test.

An alternative would be to create a Chrome extension. You can read more information about this here:

- [Managing HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#table)
- [Manifest files](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

Maybe this link can help: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/

And NO they cannot be without trickery